# Rails logrotate automatically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My production log  1GB, i need to setup logrotate automatically when the size reaches 1GB.
I am using rails 3, ruby 1.9.3.
How to rotate the log in rails?
Can any one help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i taken back up of the log file, the name of the file is "development.log.0","development.log.1".. Now i want "development.log.0.2012-09-24"(that is i want to add Time.now at the end of the file name. Can any one help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a logger which ages logfile once it reaches about 102,400,000 bytes and leave 10 old log files:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new('foo.log', 10, 102_400_000) #10 logs, about 1 GB all together
```

Comment: i want to give this statement in production.rb file?

Comment: Make an initializer appropriately named `logger.rb` instead; and thanks to @steenslag, didnt know this :-)

Comment: Thanks steenslag.
i am using like this,

config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}.log"), 10, 10*1024)

Comment: i taken back up of the log file, the name of the file is "development.log.0","development.log.1"..
Now i want "development.log.0.2012-09-24"(that is i want to add Time.now at the end of the file name. Can any one help me??

Comment: Did you intend for the log size value to be `1_024_000_000`?